# Como cambiar el tamaño de un input dentro de un td?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
<table style="min-width:70%; font-size:12px;">
    <tr style="background:#BDBDBD">
        <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">&#36;us Pto.</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo en &#36;us</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">costo en Bs.</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo Por Tonelada</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" >Zn</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" ><input size="7" style="text-align:center" type="text"></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" >Zn</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" ><input size="7" style="text-align:center" type="text" readonly></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" >Zn</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" ><input size="7" style="text-align:center" type="text" readonly></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" ><input size="7" style="text-align:center" type="text" readonly></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" ><input size="7" style="text-align:center" type="text" readonly></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Como podran notar los `input` dentro de un `td` tienen un tamaño que hace sobrar espacios a la derecha e izquierda del `td`, esto lo consegui con el atributo `size` del input.

Pero quiero que los `input`s ocupen el 100% del `td`, asi que mi pregunta es:

> Como hacer que un input ocupe el 100% de un td?

Comment: Elimina el atributo `size` y dentro del atributo `style` le agregas una ancho de 100%. asi `style="text-align:center;with:100%;"`. Espero sea lo que nesecitas o te funcione de guia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como te mencionaron en los comentarios puedes usar `width: 100%` pero esto no te funcionará bien si no cambias el [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) a `border-box`pues el valor por defecto `content-box` hace que el calculo no sea correcto como puedes comprobar aquí

```html
<table style="min-width:70%; font-size:12px;">
  <tr style="background:#BDBDBD">
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">&#36;us Pto.</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo en &#36;us</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">costo en Bs.</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo Por Tonelada</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width: 100%" type="text"></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Poniendoselo a los inputs ya lo calcula correctamente

```css
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table style="min-width:70%; font-size:12px;">
  <tr style="background:#BDBDBD">
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">&#36;us Pto.</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo en &#36;us</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">costo en Bs.</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center" width="25%" colspan="2">Costo Por Tonelada</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width: 100%" type="text"></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">Zn</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center"><input style="text-align:center; width:100%" type="text" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Este reset se usa mucho para aplicarle esta corrección a todos los elementos pero puede afectarte un layout que ya esté establecido. Lo ideal es empezar a construirlo con el reset aplicado desde el principio

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Este es uno de los cambios que aplica por defecto [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/#page-defaults) cuando lo incluyes en tu sitio.